# How to prepare the data for text generation task

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, language-model, text-generation, transformer

First, I'm not sure whether the model contains the encoder during training.

EOS means end-of-sentence. Encoder and decoder are part of transformer network.

If without-encoder, training time:

```
target: [E, F, G, H, EOS]
decoder input: [0, E, F, G, H]
```

If without-encoder, testing time:

```
decoder input: [0]
```

If with encoder, training time:

```
encoder input: [A, B, C, B]
target: [E, F, G, H, EOS]
decoder input: [0, E, F, G, H]
```

If with-encoder, testing time:

```
encoder input: [A, B, C, D]
decoder input: [0]
```

Am I exact right?

Comment: https://github.com/asyml/texar/issues/104